# Paypal IPN Custom field

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I know I can send a custom field using IPN with $_POST['custom']
But can I do that with an uploaded file? More specifically an uploaded image?

And what if I have two custom fields? I previously used something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $a.'|'.$b ?>"/>
```

But that was just text! Now I want to upload a file and I also have custom text, then I want to get it.

Is this possible and how would that look like?

Thanks!

Comment: You definitely aren't allowed to put a file in that field, but as the excellent) answer below details, you can just keep track of _where_ that file is, and call it later. It could even be a URL as to where the file can be found.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do it the way you're describing, but here's an alternative that I have used in the past.

1. Instead of having the form that contains the file upload post to PayPal, have it post to your site, and then store that uploaded file and any other custom data in a database (or any other way you choose to store it).  Assign that data an id.
2. Now redirect the user to a page that contains basically the same form, except that the input fields should be hidden, and the form will post to PayPal.  Fill in that form programmatically with the data from the previous post, and fill the 'custom' field with the id that you assigned to the custom data.  This page would also contain a JavaScript statement like this (at the bottom after the form, to ensure that it doesn't execute until the form is loaded)...

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       document.forms["paypalform"].submit();
   </script>
   ```

   ...to automatically submit the form when the page is loaded.  It's still a good idea to leave a submit button (you could style it as a link, if you want) in case the user has JavaScript disabled.  It could say something like "Click here if you are not redirected to PayPal within 10 seconds."  You could also add another message on the page such as "Redirecting to PayPal."
3. Now when you get your PDT or IPN information back from PayPal for that transaction, the 'custom' field will contain the id you assigned to the data earlier.  It's just a matter of retrieving the data from wherever you stored it.

I've done this in ASP.NET before, and I assume it would work just as well in PHP (the server-side parts), but I can't say for sure.

Note: The 'custom' field can only contain up to 256 characters.

Comment: Thanks! What about using cURL? Will Paypal accept that? Dynamically submit the paypal form. Or what about I just edit my paypal form to allow uploading the file, but have an input field that is populated with the id when the submit button is clicked through javascript and ajax.

Comment: @user924387 I'm not sure about cURL, as I haven't used it. In my solution to the problem, you are essentially submitting the form dynamically, the catch though is that you have to submit it from the user's browser (with JavaScript), otherwise the user can't be redirected to PayPal.  You can't just POST to PayPal from the server. Not with PayPal Payments Standard anyway.  You'd have to use Express Checkout or Website Payments Pro.

Comment: @user924387 The form that contains the file uploader MUST post to your website, not PayPal.  You may be able to use a jQuery AJAX file upload plugin in a separate form to upload the file, and have the PayPal form on the same page, but it would need to be submitted separately (as I said in my answer).