# Paypal IPN custom variables

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

My Paypal IPN payement is working (buy now button) but now I have to add some variables, like the discount name, the user ID, etc... in my database for each transaction. In the past I used the custom hidden field as I just need the user ID. But now I don't know how to pass this new custom variables and have them POST back form Paypal if the payement succeed ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: you should only parse cone custom var, an id, and store the rest of the data locally. use that id to retrieve the data  when paypal connects back via IPN

Comment: So it's impossible to pass other variables and have them back... With your option you mean to store it in the DB and use them after or in a Session ?

Comment: there's a limit on the custom vars, so you cant use them as an alternative to local storage.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You've got three main options:

1. Use the standard `custom` hidden field to store all the data you need in one string. You could use JSON format or some equivalent. The variable size is limited to 256 characters, which sounds like it might be enough.
2. Store a unique id in the `custom` field, and use this id to look up the other data that you've stored in your database.
3. There are also additional `option` fields you can use as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847114/can-i-send-a-variable-to-paypal-and-have-it-post-it-back-to-me-when-payment-com) and explained by PayPal [here](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_xclick_options_help_outside):

You could possibly also use some of the standard PayPal fields for purposes other than that for which they were intended (i.e., to hide your data), but this is highly dubious and entirely unnecessary, I would imagine.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631926/paypal-ipn-process-more-than-one-custom-variable).