# Issues with $_POST and adding data to db

Tags: php, mysql, post, paypal

This is my first time working with building databases and using the $_POST function. I am building a simple form with paypal IPN integration. The form is essentially just a paypal button and some dynamically filled hidden inputs, it looks like this:

deposit.php

```
<?php
$paypal_url='https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin'; // 
$paypal_id='malik@thedistractionsband.co.uk'; // Business email ID
$booking_form_id = $the_query->post->ID;
$total_amount = get_post_meta( $the_query->post->ID, 'wedding_price', true );
$deposit_amount = $total_amount*0.2;
?>

<h3>Pay Deposit</h3>
<p>Your deposit aount of £<?php echo $deposit_amount; ?> ...</p>      

<form action="<?php echo $paypal_url; ?>" method="post" name="frmPayPal1">

<input type="hidden" name="payment_type" value="deposit">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $paypal_id; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo get_post_meta( $the_query->post->ID, 'wedding_name', true ); ?> - 20% Deposit">
<input type="hidden" name="wedding_name" value="<?php echo get_post_meta( $the_query->post->ID, 'wedding_name', true ); ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="the_user" value="<?php echo $current_user->ID; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $booking_form_id; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="credits" value="510">
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $current_user->ID; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $deposit_amount; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="cpp_header_image" value="http://www.thedistractionsband.co.uk/files/2015/08/LOGO-1.1-1024x304.png">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="handling" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo get_site_url()."/payment-cancel/"; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo get_site_url()."/my-bookings/"; ?>"> 
<input name="notify_url" value="<?php echo DISTRACTIONS_LOGIN_PLUGIN_URL ?>includes/payments/paypal-ipn.php" type="hidden">

<input type="submit" border="0" name="submit" class="paypal_btn" value="PAY NOW WITH PAYPAL" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
</form>
```

You will see that the notify URL uses the file paypal-ipn.php to communicate with paypal. I also use this file to send data to a custom table in my DB if pament is successful - it's this file I'm having an issue with:

paypal-ipn.php

```
<?php
// Make wordpress functions available - so we can write to the db etc
$parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );

global $wpdb;

$item_name        = $_POST['item_name']; // wedding name
$booking_id       = $_POST['item_number']; // booking id
$user_id          = $_POST['user_id']; // user id
$user_name        = $_POST['wedding_name']; // user id
$the_user         = $_POST['the_user']; // user id
$payment_status   = $_POST['payment_status']; // payment status
$payment_amount   = $_POST['mc_gross']; // amount?
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency']; // currency
$txn_id           = $_POST['txn_id']; // transaction id
$receiver_email   = $_POST['receiver_email']; // reciever email i.e. your email
$payer_email      = $_POST['payer_email']; // payer email i.e. client email
$payment_type    = $_POST['payment_type']; // payer email i.e. client email

// Mark deposit as paid
if (strcmp ($payment_status, "Pending") == 0 || strcmp ($payment_status, "Completed") == 0) {
update_post_meta($booking_id, 'deposit_paid', 1); 

// Send email here

}

// Insert results into deposits table
$wpdb->insert( 
'wp_distr_deposit_payments', 
array( 
    'payment_user_id' => $the_user,
    'booking_id' => $booking_id, 
    'user_name' => $user_name, 
    'item_name' => $item_name, 
    'payment_status' => $payment_status, 
    'payment_amount' => $payment_amount, 
    'payment_currency' => $payment_currency, 
    'transaction_id' => $txn_id, 
    'receiver_email' => $receiver_email, 
    'user_email' => $payer_email 
), 
array( 
    '%d',   
    '%d',   
    '%s',
    '%s',   
    '%s',   
    '%d',   
    '%s',   
    '%d',   
    '%s',   
    '%s',    
) 
);

?>
```

My problem is that 2 of the fields aren't sending to the database. They are, user_name and payment_user_id

I've checked over and over and am sure it's not a syntax error. In my error_log file i'm getting the following errors:

```
[01-Dec-2015 19:56:02 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: wedding_name in /home/samskirrow/public_html/distractions-login/wp-content/plugins/distractions-login/includes/payments/paypal-ipn.php on line 11
[01-Dec-2015 19:56:02 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: the_user in /home/samskirrow/public_html/distractions-login/wp-content/plugins/distractions-login/includes/payments/paypal-ipn.php on line 12
```

Which is leading me to believe that the hidden fields in deposit.php (the_user and user_name - are not being sent/picked up by the $_POST method)

Can anyone hep me figure out a solution to get this working properly.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)`, and run the generated html through a validator. you probably have an XSS issue, making the form html invalid, and it happens to be hitting those two fields.

Comment: Yes, you probably need to `htmlentities()` the values.

Comment: side note:  you should check $_POST for an element using [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) before accessing it.

Comment: Are you sure those values are passed back from PayPal? They sound pretty [custom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780719/paypal-ipn-custom-variables).

Comment: Where does the `$current_user` object come from? If the value of `$current_user->ID` is NULL or is not set, then your input element is likely not a "successful control" which then won't get submitted.